# How to implement a splashscreen in a Poco application

Tags: poco-libraries, mitk

I find a way to catch an event/message which notify the "application loaded" event, to be able to close a splashscreen. Maybe Poco implements it directly but i haven't found any clue in the Application class documentation or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Mitk framework, and i will have to modify some code there ; the used CommonTk framework can manage a callback dedicated for splashscreen closing. Thus, there is no event published by Poco to allow this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `application` member function `bool initialized()`?

Answer (score -1):

i using POCO Thread for splash screen (where i can catch / handle status of thread). My application is programmed in WinAPI (Win32, VS C++ 2008 EE), so i using WinAPI timmers; the main message pump is also in separated thread...

Here is my WinApi32 example full code & VS90 project: [WLEZLEY_SPLASH_POCO_EXAMPLE.ZIP](http://public-code.lishack.cf/WLEZLEY_SPLASH_POCO_EXAMPLE.ZIP)

***PS:*** It works since version 1.4.5 of POCO, but also works with POCO v1.7.2 (actual version is included). You can try study my code and you try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't want to rely on a timer, but on events emitted by the framework to fine-control the splash screen (and probably other things)